# Parsing badly formatted json in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a badly formatted JSON string that needs to be parsed.
Keys of the JSON string are not wrapped in double quotes and string values are wrapped in single quotes instead of double quotes.

Example:

```
{ items: [
    { id: 1, name: 'test1' }, 
    { id: 2, name: 'test2' }
] }
```

What would be the better way to parse this JSON string?

1) Write a custom parser (how?)

2) Attempt to fix the JSON string by doing a couple of string_replace

One thing to note, the JSON string is pretty long (about 50kb) and contain quite many entries.

Comment: using a hammer to crack an egg, I would probably use a javascript engine, as this is valid in javascript, to do the evaluation for me (rhino, probably).

Comment: @njzk2 I do know it's valid in JavaScript (it was designed for it). But I need to parse it in Java. Is there a parser that would parse this well?

Comment: I assume that you don't have the option of switching to XML.

Comment: @crownjewel82 No, I don't. The JSON is provided as-is.

Comment: @mushroom: yes, hence the suggestion of use a javascript engine, such as rhino, which will evaluate it as javascript and return a java object. but if you think antlr is already too heavy...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yaml is a super set (almost) of JSon and much more forgiving.  It is much closer to what you have by default.

```
String s = "{ items: [\n" +
        "    { id: 1, name: 'test1' }, \n" +
        "    { id: 2, name: 'test2' }\n" +
        "] }";
Map map = (Map) new Yaml().load(s);
System.out.println(map);
```

prints

```
{items=[{id=1, name=test1}, {id=2, name=test2}]}
```

---

BTW This is how it dumps to Yaml by default.

```
System.out.println(new Yaml().dump(map));
```

prints

```
items:
- {id: 1, name: test1}
- {id: 2, name: test2}
```

I used [snakeyaml](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/).  You can also bind the data to class(es)

Answer (score 1):

I think [Antlr4](http://www.antlr.org/) is the best tool for the job.

You can find here an [example of a JSON grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/json/JSON.g4) that you can easily modify for your purpose, e.g., the `STRING` lexeme can be modified from:

```
STRING :  '"' (ESC | ~["\\])* '"' ;
```

to:

```
STRING :  '\'' (ESC | ~["\\])* '\'' ;
```

and you can modify the `pair` rule to look like:

```
UNQUOTEDSTRING :  (ESC | ~["\\])* ;

pair:   UNQUOTEDSTRING ':' value ;
```

Then using a listener or a visitor you can convert your modified JSON to its correct version or parse it into objects directly.

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking Antlr4 is a little too heavy for this purpose. I'm looking for the most efficient way.

Comment: @mushroom I am not sure there is a more efficient way than modifying 3 lines in the JSON grammar and writing a custom listener/visitor for the generated parser...

Comment: Just to clarify, I wasn't referring to ease of implementation but rather performance when it comes to running. Would Antlr4 be too much of a bloat to be part of an Android app?

Comment: Antlr4 is quite mature and used in a lot of production-ready projects (Pig, Hive, etc.). I can't vouch on its performance, you will have to test different alternatives by yourself, but the JSON grammar is small and simple enough that I'd be surprised if it was slow. I have to say that @PeterLawrey's solution is probably more appropriate in this case and a well fitted parser is probably more efficient than a generated one. As I always say: test the two and compare.